# Windows found errors on a drive but does not tell me with how can I find out?

Tags: windows-8.1

Windows found errors on a drive but does not tell me with how can I find out which drive it has found the errors on?

[image: We have found errors on a drive. To repair these errors and prevent loss of data restart your pc now.]

Comment: Did you look in your event log?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking:

> Does not tell me with how can I find out which drive it has found the
>   errors on?

But the error message clearly states; emphasis in bold mine:

> To repair these errors and prevent loss of data **restart your PC now**.

But if specifically knowing which drive is affected is important to you, my guess is it would be the system/boot disk. So a simple restart should clear things up. But if you have multiple drives installed you could probably [follow the manual instructions on this site](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/how-to-scan-fix-hard-drives-with-chkdsk-in-windows-8/) to use CHKDSK on each non-system disk:

> Note that CHKDSK needs to be able to lock the drive, meaning that it
>   cannot be used to examine the system’s boot drive if the computer is
>   in use. In our example, the target drive is an external disk so the
>   CHKDSK process will begin as soon as we enter the command above. If
>   the target drive is a boot disk, the system will ask you if you’d like
>   to run the command before the next boot. Type “yes,” restart the
>   computer, and the command will run before the operating system loads,
>   allowing it to gain full access to the disk.

Note the last line about the CHKDSK behavior when being run on a boot disk. From what you are showing us the system is probably already set to handle that if you reboot. But manually checking other non-system/boot disks won’t hurt much. So it’s worth a shot.

You can also see if anything in the CHKDSK log offers insight into what is happening by [following the instructions here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/96938-check-disk-chkdsk-read-event-viewer-log.html). The nicest method presented is this one which uses `powershell.exe` and will create a `CHKDSKResults.txt` file on your desktop:

```
get-winevent -FilterHashTable @{logname="Application"; id="1001"}| ?{$_.providername –match "wininit"} | fl timecreated, message | out-file Desktop\CHKDSKResults.txt
```

Since the initial **“We have found errors on a drive.”** message is what is concerning you, my guess is that the system has already run CHKDSK and as such there should be some entries in the log that would clue you into what drive issues were discovered on. Worth checking out if you are wary of doing anything else.

Comment: I fully understand that it will repair them when i restart the computer, and i intend to restart it but currently im installing some software that is taking a long time... and i would like to know which drive has the error... and ill try your powershell test solution as soon as the installation is done.